# Android xml layout and adding a custom view written in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I've created a custom view XML layout resource `MyView.xml`. Can I refer to `MyView` by the XML layout file inside a second XML layout such as `main.xml`? If so, how?

(To be clear, I'm not looking for replies that explain how to inflate views from within my Java code, or that explain introducing Java classes in XML layout resources with `<com.MyDomain.App.MyView ...>` unless this helps here or to clarify that I have no other option.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your XML file is like `/res/layout/MyView.xml` you can refer to in `main.xml` with

`<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”utf-8”?>`

`...`

`<include layout="@layout/MyView.xml" />`

`...`

Comment: And later use it with `<MyView ...>` as usual?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Anyway `<include>` will include your predefined layout(s) as is from `MyView.xml` directly in `main.xml` after that no need to call or refer to any layout(s) you put in `main.xml`

Comment: Oh - I see, thanks. I'd misunderstood that <include> might appear at the top of the XML layout, like in header files. That's not the case.